# My black text isn't black after exporting to PDF

Tags: export, color

Consider any standard plot, with true CMYK black text:

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 99], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]] - 2};
myplot = DateListPlot[fakedata, Joined -> True, 
  BaseStyle -> {20, CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I `Export` to PDF format, the text does not reproduce as true CMYK black, even if I specify its color as a `CMYKColor`. Rather, it comes out as `CMYKColor[1,1,1,1]`, a mix of all four CMYK colors. This is a nuisance as my use case is to export these graphics for importing into an InDesign document, and the result is fuzzy-looking text. Strangely, the plot's `Frame` is not affected by this problem, which makes me think it is something to do with the text rendering algorithm.

Using `ColorConvert` doesn't help because that just rasterizes the image, which looks terrible. It is designed for images, not vector graphics.

```
 Export["test-converted3.pdf", ColorConvert[myplot, "CMYK"]] (* ugliness ensues *)
```

**While I can fix the problem by getting the graphic designer to re-distill the PDF, I would much prefer to have a direct solution in Mathematica.**

There is a supposedly obsolete option `ColorOutput -> "CMYK"`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I considered that the issue might be something to do with the way Mathematica antialiases text, but I couldn't work out what setting might affect that. Does anyone have any suggestions for a direct Mathematica solution?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Haha - no, it's a do-it-in-my-lunchtimes-on-top-of-my-official-job problem :-D

Comment: An EPS file exported seems to preserve the CMYK value: `0 0 0 1 k`. Don't know whether EPS->PDF conversion changes it though, and you may be using translucency...

Comment: @cormullion unfortunately EPS -> PDF is not an option because of font substitution issues.

Comment: @cormullion Exporting to EPS and converting generated EPS to PDF by Acrobat Distiller 11 I get all the text being `Black(1.0)` in `DeviceGray color space` according to the Preflight output and no CMYK colors at all in the PDF file. But yes, the EPS file contains `0 0 0 1 k` operators - but I am not sure whether they correspond to the text or only to lines.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, but the PDF file exported from *Mathematica* 8.0.4 does not have CMYK text at all. All the text and `GridLines` are RGB and only `Frame` and `FrameTicks` are CMYK (but not frame tick labels). Here is output of Preflight in Acrobat 11.0.5:

[image: screenshot]

I cannot check the output of *Mathematica* 9, but I suppose that the text is exported actually in RGB mode and is converted to CMYK when imported into the InDesign document.